# Failing at SSH Agent Forwarding

Tags: ssh, sshd, ssh-agent, forwarding

I have a DigitalOcean droplet into which I'm attempting to clone a repo from Github.

This works fine on my local machine, and I've been following the guide from Github here:

https://docs.github.com/en/developers/overview/using-ssh-agent-forwarding

I had to manually enable SSH Agent with `eval $(ssh-agent -s)` on the server but as far as I can tell agent forwarding is not occurring since I get no access using `ssh -T git@github.com` from the server, the debug output from `ssh -v git@github.com` is:

```
OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.5, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to github.com [140.82.121.3] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.5
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version babeld-181fb29f
debug1: no match: babeld-181fb29f
debug1: Authenticating to github.com:22 as 'git'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:p2QAMXNIC1TJYWeIOttrVc98/R1BUFWu3/LiyKgUfQM
The authenticity of host 'github.com (140.82.121.3)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:p2QAMXNIC1TJYWeIOttrVc98/R1BUFWu3/LiyKgUfQM.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,140.82.121.3' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 
debug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_xmss 
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

In the local machine I have created a config entry for the server IP:

```
Host x.x.x.x
    ForwardAgent yes
```

I have also edited the sshd_config file on the server to:

```
AllowAgentForwarding yes
```

I have added the local key on my local machine using: `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa`

I don't know what else to do, and I've been beating my head against this for hours. (I've read everything I can find but nothing helped.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My mistake was attempting to debug the problem using the provided DigitalOcean console window - it dawned on me slowly that maybe that did not have the necessary access to perform forwarding. And of course it doesn't because it's sitting in a browser window.

So I scrapped everything went back to basics and used a terminal for SSH access, and suddenly I was getting useful error messages.

In the end, I expanded the config entry on my local machine to:

```
Host digitalocean    
    User root
    ForwardAgent yes
    Hostname x.x.x.x
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/digitalocean
```

And then I was able to access github on the server with `ssh -T git@github.com`

Solved.

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable ssh-agent in your local machine (not in the server) and add your keys to it.

Comment: I can see that's unclear in what I wrote but I did enable it on the local machine, not the server.

Comment: Sorry - I mean, it was already enabled on the local machine and the comment toward the end says I added the key to it (I've clarified that I added it on the local machine).